# How to add xmlns="MyNamespace" to AuthSOAPHeader in gSOAP

Tags: gsoap

I'm building a client application to access a web service from a 3rd party server.

From this server WSDL:

```
<s:element name="AuthSOAPHeader" type="tns:AuthSOAPHeader" />
<s:complexType name="AuthSOAPHeader">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="s:string" />
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
  </s:sequence>
  <s:anyAttribute />
</s:complexType>
```

And these commands:

```
wsdl2h -k -o svc.h .\svc.asmx.xml
soapcpp2 -i -C .\svc.h
```

My gSOAP-based client application is generating this XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns1:AuthSOAPHeader>
    <User>user</User>
    <Password>password</Password>
  </ns1:AuthSOAPHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

But my server only responds to:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns1:AuthSOAPHeader xmlns="Server.WebServices">
    <User>user</User>
    <Password>password</Password>
  </ns1:AuthSOAPHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I'm struggling to figure out a way to add the **xmlns="Server.WebServices"** attribute to the **AuthSOAPHeader** tag.  Is there a way to do this in gSOAP?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this by adding this flag to the soap initialization:

```
SOAP_XML_DEFAULTNS
```